# Livewire form content dissapears

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have this code in a livewire view which contains a form. This is a simple select field in which you are supposed to select a document type from a list.

```
<div>
    <label for="documenttype" class="form-label"><strong>Document type</strong></label>
    <select wire:model="documenttype_id" class="form-control" id="documenttype" aria-describedby="documenttypeHelp">
        <option selected>{{ __( 'Choose' ) }}</option>
        @foreach( $documenttypes as $documenttype )
            <option value="{{ $documenttype->id }}" @if( isset( $documenttype_id ) && ( $documenttype_id == $documenttype->id ) ) selected @endif>
                {{ $documenttype->name }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

The thing is that I want it to have preselected the correct value when editing a client. But for some reason when I add this code: `@if( isset( $documenttype_id ) && ( $documenttype_id == $documenttype->id ) ) selected @endif` in the options loop, the form starts behaving strangely.
Everytime the person filling the form selects an option the content becomes blank.

This is situation 1 (before selecting an option):

[image]

And this is situation 2 (after selecting the option):

[image]

I have no idea why this happens, can someone guide me on how to solve this issue?

Comment: add wire:ignore.self to root select's div

Comment: Can you please post the answer, so I can validate it as the correct answer? @Prospero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add wire:ignore.self to root select's div. Using this modifier, you instruct Livewire don´t update the element itself but allows modification to its children.

Answer (score 0):

The quick way to fix this would be to assign the selected value from your component `mount` method.

```
public function mount() {

    $this->documenttype_id = $client->documenttype_id
    //$client->documenttype_id being the previously selected value from your db
}
```

this will automatically select your option, you don't need the if statement on your option tag.